# How can I add roles from an external db after a user has been loggedin successfully

Tags: keycloak

We want to integrate Keycloak 18 in our platform to replace a self-implemented solution in the future. The first step was to implement an own user provider to keep our existing tables where users, roles and permissions are stored. This was pretty easy. So the old and new way can co-exist for a step-by-step replacement.

Now we also want to provide integrations for other user providers, like LDAP, Kerberos etc.
Is there a way to load the roles from our external db table after a user was authenticated by a random user provider?

e.g.:

1. User sends auth request to keycloak
2. User has been successfully authenticated by the ldap user provider
3. lookup external db to get the roles for the username and add them to the user model

thank you for your help

Comment: For LDAP you have especially mapper to map ldap-groups to realm roles, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: no, I want to get the roles to an user from my external db. (after the login by the ldap provider was successful)

Comment: the user comes from an external DB or from an LDAP provider?

Comment: this should be indifferent. The customer should be able to use keycloak's internal management or ldap or a self implemented user provider. I want to write code which adds roles after a user was authenticated by any provider

Comment: I think there are at least 3 options: 1. Adding a new authenticator 2. Adding an event listener 3. Adding a dummy required action that always passes but adds some roles to the user

Comment: I tried my luck with option 2. It works and solved my problem. Thank you Paul!

Comment: @peacekiller I'm trying to implement the same thing as your issue. Could you provide an example on how you were able to do this?